# Run Grunt commands from PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, node.js

To run grunt commands from PHP on my Mac I can use `putenv` to tell PHP where NodeJS lives and the global PATH so I can run grunt commands like:

```
putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/usr/local/bin');
exec('grunt watch');
```

But on Windows 7, NodeJS is in a different location...

I first tried:

```
putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs');
```

Which is where NodeJS itself lives, but this doesn't work...

and then tried:

```
putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':C:\Users\cameron.drysdale\AppData\Roaming\npm');
```

Which is where the npm lives (I don't know why on Windows it lives in a diff location to the exe). But again this doesn't work and I get an error that grunt is an unknown command. grunt-cli is definitely installed globally!

Any ideas on what the path should be for Windows?

Comment: It's been a couple of years since I last used Windows, but isn't the separator on Windows between paths a `;` instead of a `:` ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use both!

```
$putenv = putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ';C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;C:\Users\cameron.drysdale\AppData\Roaming\npm');
```

and also use `;` instead of `:` for the seperator (as commented by Pieter Hoste)